# The device does not recognize this host. when trying iphone 4 with iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

i have app that i run successfully on iphone 5 with iOS 8.1 
now with the free provisioning i like to test the app on iphone 4 with iOS 7.1
but after successfully compiling the app when i try to run it with the play button im getting :

```
The device does not recognize this host.
Please check your setup and try again. (0xE800001C).
```

[image]

also the deployment target is 5.1 
[image]

what can be the problem ? using Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure out a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 10):

It worked for me when i reconnect device and you will get a popup like this

[image]

And then click on **Trust**. After that it will take some time to copying data to your computer and then you can use this device in xcode.